# Sysgen vs. Pure VHDL for Image Processing Implementation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

We're evaluating whether to implement a complex image processing algorithm using Matlab's Sysgen or translate it directly into VHDL.

As a start, the algorithm is given to us in Matlab.

Traditionally, teams have implemented the algorithms using Matlab's Sysgen. However, it hasn't been the most maintainable or testable code.

This was okay in the past, since the implementation was only for R&D. Now however we're designing for mission where we can't have any failures.

On the team, it seems the more FPGA experienced folks prefer VHDL.

Pure VHDL or do model based design in Sysgen? Thoughts?

Comment: hm no matter who or what writes your code, you're still responsible for constructing a proper test bench around it. I don't non sysgen, but I'd probably trust matlab-generated code to implement what you specified it should with less bugs than human-generated code, but that has limits (specification that is interpretable by a program is essentially code, so you're simply using a tool to allow humans to write code in a language they're better suited for)